# Template alias for template member class

Tags: c++, c++11

I have the following template

```
template<class F>
struct A{
  template<int N>
  struct B{
    using type = int;
  };
};
```

I'd like to make a template alias, however:

```
//doesn't compile.
template<class F, int N >
using alias_A = typename A<F>::B<N>::type;

GCC:
question.cpp:12:36: error: expected ';' before '::' token
 using alias_A = typename A<F>::B<N>::type;
                                    ^
question.cpp:12:36: error: 'type' in namespace '::' does not name a type
```

When debugging I find:

```
//does compile
struct C{};
using alias_B = typename A<C>::B<0>::type;
```

Can somebody point out what I'm doing wrong? I feel I'm missing something obvious.

Comment: Late note: Clang gives a more helpful `error: use 'template' keyword to treat 'B' as a dependent template name` ([link](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/1c8d3c351c8c6724))

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to tell C++ that it the inner type `B<N>` is a template:

```
template<class F, int N >
using alias_A = typename A<F>::template B<N>::type;
```

In this case, the compiler parses what you've written as `operator<`, not as the opening brace for a template parameter.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/610245/where-and-why-do-i-have-to-put-the-template-and-typename-keywords) post gives an exhaustive rundown on when and why you need to do this.